# Work environment simulator

Tags: f#, simulation

This code attempts to solve a [suggested challenge by myself a while back on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7314/22270), transcribed here for simplicity.

> ## Allocate resources efficiently on a work environment
>
> The company Code42Review demands that their **employees** are able to
> handle **work items** as efficiently as possible.
>
> Those **work items** are assigned according to the **work item
> chooser** that decides which work items get assigned to which
> employees.  The work item chooser takes into account the **skills**
> needed by a certain work item and tries to match them as close as
> possible to the skills of an employee. While some skills are mandatory
> others are "nice to have". The work item chooser may delay assignment
> due to not having any employee available with a required skill.
>
> A **work item** only exists if a **work candidate** has **acquired all
> resources** sucessfully.  Acquiring a resource is a process that may
> require time, in this particular work envoirnment, up to 20 seconds.
> The process of acquiring a resource is not guarteed to succeed because
> such resources might not be available. (the successful rate of
> resource acquisition is tipically under 50%)
>
> In this work enviorment an employee may take up to several minutes to
> complete a work item. Usually something between 2 and 20 minutes. An
> employee that is handling a work item is considered to be busy and may
> not have another work item assigned to him.
>
> A work item should be assigned to an employee within the shortest
> amount of time possible, if it's not assigned to an employee within a
> reasonable time,  the resources may no longer be available. In this
> scenario the work item will be replaced by another.

I am just covering the very basics of my challenge. I have a work producer that keeps producing work items if at least one worker is available. The work item is assigned to the first available employee. I also keep track of the time that each employee has worked and the amount of time each employee has waited.

This is my first time trying to do something in [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23) so it's only natural that there will be lots of things to improve.

The module `WorkItem` is where most of the code is at. Basically there is `WorkItem` type that represents a workitem in any given state (new, assigned, completed).

There is the operation `assignWorkItem` to assign a `workItem` to a worker.

The operation `completeWorkItem` to complete a `workItem`.

The `handleWork` which is basically waiting a random amount of time, simulating the worker getting the work item done.

And the `workitemCreator` that is able to create work items based on a policy (which employee should perform said work item).

```
module WorkItem

open System
open System.Threading.Tasks
open System.Linq
open System.Threading

    [<StructuredFormatDisplay("{Date} - {FastTime}")>]
    type TimeReference() =
        let time = DateTime.UtcNow
        let now = Environment.TickCount
        member x.FastTime = now
        member x.Date = time
        static member (-) (a : TimeReference, b : TimeReference) = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds (float (a.FastTime - b.FastTime))
    
    type WorkResult =
        | FullyCompleted
        | NotAssignedInTime
        | Abandoned
        | AssigneeAbandoned

    type Assignee = {
        mutable isBusy:bool; 
        name:string; 
        mutable totalWorkTime:int64; 
        mutable totalWaitTime:int64; 
        mutable lastCompletedTime:TimeReference
    }

    let createWorker name =
        {isBusy = false; name = name; totalWorkTime = 0L; totalWaitTime = 0L; lastCompletedTime = new TimeReference()}
        
    type NewWorkItem = {
        createdAt:TimeReference
    }

    type AssignedWorkItem = {
        createdAt:TimeReference; 
        assignedAt:TimeReference; 
        firstAssignee:Assignee
    }

    type FinnishedWorkItem =  {
        createdAt:TimeReference; 
        assignedAt:TimeReference option; 
        firstAssignee:Assignee option; 
        completedAt:TimeReference; 
        workResult:WorkResult
    }

    type WorkItem =
        | NewWorkItem of NewWorkItem
        | AssignedWorkItem of AssignedWorkItem
        | CompletedWorkItem of FinnishedWorkItem

    
    let assignWorkItem (item:NewWorkItem) (assignee:Assignee) =  
        if not assignee.isBusy then
            assignee.isBusy <- true
            Some (AssignedWorkItem {
                createdAt = item.createdAt; 
                assignedAt = new TimeReference(); 
                firstAssignee = assignee
            })
        else 
            None

    let completeWorkItem (item:AssignedWorkItem) workTime =
        item.firstAssignee.totalWorkTime <- item.firstAssignee.totalWorkTime + workTime
        item.firstAssignee.lastCompletedTime <- new TimeReference();
        item.firstAssignee.isBusy <- false
        printfn "%A WorkT-%A WaitT-%A" item.firstAssignee.name 
            (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(float item.firstAssignee.totalWorkTime)) 
            (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(float item.firstAssignee.totalWaitTime)) 
        CompletedWorkItem {
            createdAt = item.createdAt; 
            assignedAt = Some item.assignedAt;
            firstAssignee = Some item.firstAssignee;
            completedAt = new TimeReference();
            workResult = FullyCompleted
        }
        
    let assigneeAbandonWorkItem (item:AssignedWorkItem) =
        CompletedWorkItem {
            createdAt = item.createdAt; 
            assignedAt = Some item.assignedAt;
            firstAssignee = Some item.firstAssignee;
            completedAt = new TimeReference();
            workResult = AssigneeAbandoned
        }

    let private createWorkItem chance =
        Enumerable.Range(1, Utils.accumulativeChance chance |> fst)
        |> Seq.map (fun  _ -> Utils.randTime (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)) (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12.0)))
        |> Seq.iter (fun delay -> 
            Task.Delay(delay) |> Async.AwaitTask |> ignore
        )
        { createdAt = new TimeReference() }

    type assignmentPolicy = Assignee list -> Assignee Option
    type workProduced = AssignedWorkItem -> Assignee -> Unit
    type workThroughputConstrainer = Assignee list -> bool
    
    let firstAvailablePolicy (workers: Assignee list) =
        workers
        |> Seq.tryFind(fun worker -> not worker.isBusy)

    let handleWork (assignment:AssignedWorkItem) (worker:Assignee) =
        printfn "%A is handling %A" worker.name assignment.createdAt
        let workTime = Utils.randTime (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0)) (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20.0))
        let elapsed = (new TimeReference() - worker.lastCompletedTime).TotalMilliseconds
        worker.totalWaitTime <- worker.totalWaitTime + int64 elapsed
        Thread.Sleep(workTime)
        completeWorkItem assignment (int64 workTime.TotalMilliseconds)

    let shouldCreateWorkItem (workers:Assignee list) =
        workers
        |> Seq.exists (fun worker -> not worker.isBusy)

    let workitemCreator chance (workers:Assignee list) (assignmentPolicy:assignmentPolicy) (constrainer:workThroughputConstrainer) =
        Utils.createTimer 100 (fun _ -> 
            if not (constrainer workers) then ()
            let work = createWorkItem chance
            let worker = assignmentPolicy workers
            match worker with
            | Some worker -> 
                let assignment = assignWorkItem work worker
                match assignment with
                | Some (AssignedWorkItem assignment) -> handleWork assignment worker |> ignore
                | _ -> ()
            | None -> ()
            ()
        )
    
    let firstAvailableWorkItemCreator workers = workitemCreator 0.5 workers firstAvailablePolicy shouldCreateWorkItem
```

```
module Utils
    open System

    let rand = Random()
        
    /// Generates a random time between min and max Timespans
    let randTime (min:TimeSpan) (max:TimeSpan) =
        let time = rand.Next(int min.TotalMilliseconds, int max.TotalMilliseconds)
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(float time)
            
    /// Generates compounding random probailities until it reaches the sucessRate.
    /// Meaning that as each probability is generate it is multiplied by all previously generated ones.
    ///
    /// Example: sucessRate = 20% = 0.2
    /// Probability = 1 - successRate = 0.8
    ///
    /// Generated probabilities:
    ///
    /// 1. 10% = 0.1 (compounding = 0.1 < 0.8)
    /// 2. 12% = 0.12 (compounding = 0.232 < 0.8)
    /// 3. 60% = 0.6 (compounding = 0.9712 >= 0.8)
    ///
    /// Returning (3, 0.9712), thus the finally returned probability can be bigger than 1
    let accumulativeChance successRate =
        let mutable currentOdd = 0.0
        let mutable iterations = 0
        while currentOdd < successRate do
            let odd = currentOdd + 1.0
            currentOdd <- 1.0 - odd * (1.0 + rand.NextDouble())
            iterations <- iterations + 1
        (iterations, currentOdd)

    let createTimer timerInterval eventHandler =
        let timer = new System.Timers.Timer(float timerInterval)
        timer.AutoReset <- true
        timer.Elapsed.Add eventHandler
        timer.Start()
```

```
open System
open WorkItem
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{Date} - {FastTime}")>]
type TimeReference() =
    let time = DateTime.UtcNow
    let now = Environment.TickCount
    member x.FastTime = now
    member x.Date = time
    static member (-) (a : TimeReference, b : TimeReference) = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds (float (a.FastTime - b.FastTime))
    
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let workers = [createWorker "Bob"; createWorker "Alice"]
    WorkItem.firstAvailableWorkItemCreator workers
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```